# Probability - What is the probability that the two-digit number is a multiple of 3

Tags: probability

I don't know why I am wrong. According to the problem, since $de$ is a multiple of $3$, eith $d$ or $e$ has to be $6$. But my answer is wrong. The correct answer is $\frac13$.

> Digit $d$ is randomly selected from the set $\{4,5,6,7\}$. Without replacement of $d$, another digit $e$ is selected. What is the probability that the two-digit number $de$ is a multiple of $3$? Express  your answer as a common fraction.

Comment: But $45$ qualifies, as does $54$, and some others.

Comment: Does "the two-digit number $de$" mean the number with tens digit $d$ and ones digit $e$? Or does it mean the product of $d$ and $e$?

Comment: @kccu I look at my book. There is a line under $de$. Should it means $d$ is the tens digit and $e$ is ones digit?

Comment: @learning I'm not sure. You will have to look through your book to see if that notation is defined or explained anywhere. My guess is it probably does mean $d$ is the tens digit and $e$ is the ones digit, which is consistent with the answer below (which also gives $1/3$ as the probability).

Comment: " since de is a multiple of 3, eith d or e has to be 6"  Where on earth did you get that idea?  12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,99 are all exceptions.  The only numbers where this *is* true is 36,60,63,66,69,96.

Comment: $d + e$ should be divisible by 3 not both $d$ and $e$ equals six.

Comment: I missunderstood the problem. When you wrote $de$ and $ed$ you are refer to multiplication or concatenation of two digits?

Comment: There are $12$ and $4$ of them are multiples of three

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Either $d$ or $e$ has to be $6$", this is incorrect.

In order for the number $de$ to be divisible by $3$, the sum of the two digits $(d+e)$ should be a multiple of $3$. Therefore, $(d+e)=(4+5)$ or $(5+7)$

Proof:
Suppose you have a three-digit number $abc$

Then$$abc=100a+10b+c=99a+9b+0c+(a+b+c)$$
if $abc$ is divisible by $3$, then $99a+9b+0c+(a+b+c)$ must also be divisible by 3.
Now because $99a,9b,0c$ can clearly be divided by $3$ (because of $99$), so $(a+b+c)$ must be a multiple by $3$.

For higher-digit numbers this proof also holds.

Comment: Why does the sum of the two digits (d+e) should be a multiple of 3?

Comment: @learning Well it's a common trick. You can test any multiple of 3 and you would find that correct. I will edit the answer and add a short proof to give you a sense.

Comment: Note $(6+6)$ is not a possibility since $d$ and $e$ are chosen without replacement.

Comment: @kccu Thanks edited